# Running continuous events after each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to make this for 2 days, I apologize I'm new to Javascript/Jquery and I'm in the learning process.

I'm trying to create a javascript when the page is loaded will have an image fade in and fade out and after the first image fades in and out then a second, third, etc. however many I need.

I know this is a newby question but I'm clearly not sure what to look for at this point. And I have been doing research and learning along the way, I just would like to have it sooner than I may be able to accomplish.

Any help is appreciated.

This is what I came up with which to me looks completely invalid, but seems to work:

```
    <div class="splashbg1" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="splashbg2" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="splashbg3" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="splashbg4" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="splashbg5" style="display: none;"></div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.splashbg1').fadeIn(1300, function() {
    $('.splashbg1').fadeOut(1300, function() {
    $('.splashbg2').fadeIn(1300, function() {
    $('.splashbg2').fadeOut(1300, function() {
    $('.splashbg3').fadeIn(1300, function() {
    $('.splashbg3').fadeOut(1300, function() {
    $('.splashbg4').fadeIn(1300, function() {
    $('.splashbg4').fadeOut(1300, function() {
    $('.splashbg5').fadeIn(1300, function() {
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow could you post the html and the code which your working on so we can point to specific problems

Comment: If you are looking to learn; minitech has a beautiful answer. If you need a product for production or use, try any of the existing plugins for jQuery. Search term is 'jQuery carousel' : http://www.agilecarousel.com/flavor_2.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example HTML:

```
<div id="images>
    <img src="">
    <img src="">
    ...
</div>
```

example Javascript:

```
function switchImage(){
    $('#images img:visible').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).next().length ? $(this).next().fadeIn() : $('#images img').eq(0).fadeIn();
    });
};
$('#images img').hide().eq(0).show(); // show only the first image
setInterval(switchImage, 2000); // loop through images every 2000 milliseconds
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ampersand/nhp2v/

Comment: Awesome thanks! This works more closely with what I was looking for. Sorry again, how do I make it stop rotating once it's at the end of the images?

Comment: this version: http://jsfiddle.net/ampersand/nhp2v/3/ will stop when it reaches the last image. If you have any questions about the code, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and a variable containing the current image, then fade them in and out. It depends on how your images are stored. If you have one `<img>` element with an ID of `myImg`, for example, you could do this:

```
var images = ['http://someurl.com/someimg.jpg', 'somethingelse.png', 'hello.gif'];
var currentImage = 0;

function next() {
    $('#myImg').fadeOut(function() {
        $('#myImg').prop('src', images[currentImage]).fadeIn(); // Set the image and fade in
        currentImage++; // Get ready for the next image
    });
}

next();
```

If you wanted it to wrap, you could do `images[currentImage % images.length]`. If there are a bunch of different images, you can do about the same thing, just keep the IDs of the images in `images` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick function called `sequence` below. Make a list of the images you'd like to animate using jQuery selectors like this:

```
var list = [
    $('first'),
    $('second'),
    $('third')
    ];
```

Then call the function below with something like this `sequence( list, 200, function(){} );`

```
var sequence = function( array, duration, callback ){
    var list = array,
        length = list.length,
        i = 0,
        duration = duration,
        callback = callback;

    function chainFade(){
        if( i < length )
            array[i].fadeIn( duration )
                    .fadeOut( duration, function(){
                        i++;
                        chainFade();
                    });
        else
            typeof callback == 'function' && callback();
    }
    chainFade();
};
```

I haven't tested it yet so let me know if you run into any bugs.